# what is the difference between ofstream and ifstream?

Tags: c++

In `ofstream` you can set the mode to be read files, e.g.

```
 std::ofstream of(filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::in);
```

Then what is the difference between it and `ifstream`?

Comment: try to use `operator<<` on an `istream` ...

Answer (score 2):

`ofstream` is for output or writing files. `ifstream` is for input or reading files.

According to  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

> - out is always set for ofstream objects (even if explicitly not set in argument mode).
>     Note that even though ofstream is an output stream, its internal filebuf object may be set to also support input operations

Answer (score 0):

`ofstream` and `ifstream` are totally different classes. Although you can open the underlying file of `ofstream` under input mode, it does not support input methods such as `operator>>`, `get` and so on.